# Radio & Dropdown to same observable - Knockout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have same observable value assigned for radio list "checked" databind and for drop down list "value" databind

```
 <select name="controls" data-bind="options: cars(), optionsText:'make', optionsValue:'id', value: $root.selectedId, optionsCaption: 'Select One'"> </select>

 <div data-bind="foreach: cars">
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="controls" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedId, checkedValue: id, value: id"><div data-bind="text:make">
      </div>
</div>
```

Since, drop down always holds some value by default 'Select One' or selected value. Not allowing the user to make selection on radio button list. When user clicks on radio buttonn its not getting checked/selection.

I can fix by two different observables, but due to some reason I want to stay with same observable

jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9vm01e3r/2/

Comment: Could you please provide a working fiddle?

Comment: @AldoRomo88 Included fiddle. For some reason, radio button is not populated from observable array. But similar issue with other radio button. jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9vm01e3r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the provided fiddle I identify two different problems in your html

1. Inside a `foreach` binding context is changed to current item, you need to use `$parent` to access to `selectedCar` property.
2. Input/radio was inside a label with a text binding, when this binding is processed is replacing all inner content

Your html should looks something like this

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: cars">
 <label data-bind="text:name"></label>
 <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedCar, checkedValue: id, value: id" />
 </div>
```

**Edit**

Ok I know what is happening, when you click an option from radios that item is not a valid item for select tag because isn't  in `options` array, then  knockout sets `value` to undefined causing radios to be deselected.

So one alternative will be to use `valueAllowUnset: true` on select tag (documentation [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements))

Please se this updated fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/tbdo4rxq/

Comment: Great!! This fixed my 95% of the issue. When I pick something from radio list. The dropdown is getting blank. Is it possible to make default "Select One"

Comment: I don't think that it's possible, for that effect you will need a more complex solution maybe your original propose to use different observables

Comment: Is it possible to set dropdown to default(--Select One--) using click event on the radio button?

Comment: It sound a little strange to me, because you will be violating mvvm principales. In you view "Select One"  means that view model has an undefined value on property selectedCar, you probably need mutually exclusive selects, or two selects one for manufacturer and other for cars (filtered by selected manufactured) that sounds more natural for me.